# Add many element into list without instantiate too many object

Tags: java, arrays, memory

I have a for loop like and an `ArrayList` as follow:

```
List<VehicleImpl> vehicles = new ArrayList<VehicleImpl>();
for(int i = 0; i < input.getNoVehicles(); i++) {
                                            //Name vehicle by index
    VehicleImpl vehicle = VehicleImpl.Builder.newInstance("vehicle " + String.valueOf(i+1))
            //The first location - depot location is indexed as 0 in Matrices
            .setStartLocation(Location.newInstance(i))
            .setBreak(lunch)
            .setLatestArrival(input.getOperating())
            .setType(type)
            .build();
    vehicles.add(vehicle);
}
```

So, I want to ask: Is there any way I instantiate the `VehicleImpl` outside the loop and use the **ONLY ONE** instance. For each iteration, I modify the instance add the new version of instance to the list.

Comment: No. You would modify everything you add to the list, as the reference would be the same for all objects. You must have one separate instance for each different object.

Comment: You might want to revisit the meaning of "object" and "instance". If you have only one instance that means you have only one object. And if you add that to the list multiple times you'd still have only one element referenced by multiple "slots". What makes you want to reduce the number of objects in the first place?

Comment: If you instantiation your vehicle outside the loop you will add the same vehicle to the list on each iteration step

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you have to clone the first intance at leat (By using BeanUtils for example).

Then you just update the startLocation attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate the builder outside the loop, which would halve the number of objects you're creating, but only if you were to change the builder's constructor to have zero arguments, moving the vehicle name into a setter. For example:

```
List<VehicleImpl> vehicles = new ArrayList<VehicleImpl>();

VehicleImpl.Builder builder = VehicleImpl.Builder.newInstance();

for(int i = 0; i < input.getNoVehicles(); i++) {

    VehicleImpl vehicle = builder
            //Name vehicle by index
            .setName("vehicle " + String.valueOf(i+1))
            //The first location - depot location is indexed as 0 in Matrices
            .setStartLocation(Location.newInstance(i))
            .setBreak(lunch)
            .setLatestArrival(input.getOperating())
            .setType(type)
            .build();
    vehicles.add(vehicle);
}
```

This is somewhat more error prone because values in the builder are not reset on each new iteration. That's not necessarily a problem for you right now, but if you were to add conditional logic, you'd probably start having a lot of problems. However, if your goal is to reduce the number of objects created, this will satisfy that.

Comment: That only works if the builder doesn't have any invisible internal state that needs to be reset after `build`, though.

Comment: @MalteHartwig Sure. I think I'd be surprised if a builder functioned that way and it's the kind of thing that ought to be documented if it did. It looks like OP is the author of the vehicle and its builder so he'll know whether or not that's the case.

Comment: Right, just wanted to point out the possibility. If, for example, the builder creates an empty Vehicle instance internally, and set its attributes with each setter call, then it would have to create a new instance after the call to `build`, otherwise it will override the previous instance's attributes. That's an assumption, of course; the builder might be perfectly fine.